# adding information in docker config.json

Tags: docker

I had one question on how can I add "author field" inside config.json file in a docker image.
For ex:
I pulled a ubuntu image from docker hub and saved it as a tar using docker save. Then I extracted the contents of the tar file in that it contained a .json file
The config.json file contains a tag history with the following contents:

"history": [
{
"created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"author": "Bazel",
"created_by": "bazel build ..."
},
{
"created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"author": "XYZ",
"created_by": "XYZ build ..."
},
{
"created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"author": "XYZ",
"created_by": "XYZ build ..."
},
{
"created": "2021-02-18T19:34:55.646987803Z",
"created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY  in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 "
},

How can I add the author field in the last row ?
Thank you